# How to send response from servlet to client side?

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to send response in form of an .xml file from a Java servlet to the client. For that I have written the code below:

```
if (result) {
    response.setContentType("text/xml");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("<Login>");
    out.println("<status>"+successStatus+"</status>");
    out.println("<username>"+userDTO.getFirstname()+"</username>");
    out.println("<sessionId>"+hSession.getId()+"</sessionId>");
    out.println("<timestamp>"+hSession.getLastAccessedTime()+"</timestamp>");
    out.println("<timeout>"+hSession.getLastAccessedTime()+"</timeout>");
    out.println("</Login>");
}
```

How can I check on the client whether I get this response or not?
Do I need to send the response explicitly or is the above code sufficient to send the response to the client?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to know whether above code "is sufficient", then test it.

Comment: Why would you post a question like this without even having tested your pasted code? If tested, post the errors you got, if any, and explain us how you tested it, what the results are, etc.,

Comment: @chiccodoro sir i m new to java and i dont kno much about servlets.i m debugging it but while debugging,after this its not going to client side code.so i m not getting that how to check on client side whether its getting response or not.so please help me sir.

Comment: @pritsag: It's o.k. to be new to any topic, but nobody can help you if you don't tell us what you expect and what you got instead, and hardly anybody is willing to help you if you accept so few answers to your past questions.

Comment: @pritsag: If you want to know whether the server response works, simply open the corresponding URL in a web browser and see what you get there.

Answer (score 4):

Just invoking the servlet's URL will get you to the client side (browser). You don't need to do anything specific.

So, if your servlet is mapped like this,

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.test.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Just invoking the URL `http://www.example.com/context/MyServlet` will get you the XML on the browser!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
                               throws ServletException, IOException {

    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

    out.println("<HTML>");
    out.println("<HEAD><TITLE>Hello World</TITLE></HEAD>");
    out.println("<BODY>");
    out.println("<BIG>Hello World</BIG>");
    out.println("</BODY></HTML>");
  }
}
```